# Handle PUT and DELETE requests in TIdHTTPServer in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-7, indy-9

Is it possible to handle PUT and DELETE requests in TIdHTTPServer (Indy 9, Delphi 7)?

I have tried OnCommandGet but it handles only GET and POST requests.

Also I have tried OnCommandOther event. It handles PUT and DELETE methods but I can not access to sent data.

What I do wrong?

Comment: You write that you can not access the request body (data) in PUT and DELETE. It should work in the same way as with POST - in Indy 9 and 10, data is in the RequestInfo.PostStream property.

Comment: Actually, it only works that way in Indy 10, but not in Indy 9.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it *possible*? Yes.  However, in Indy 9, `TIdHTTPServer` only parses `HEAD`, `GET` and `POST` requests, and only if the `OnCommandGet` event is assigned.  If the `OnCommandGet` event is not assigned, or a different request is received, `TIdHTTPServer` **DOES NOT** parse the request at all (except for the first line to determine the request type), and triggers the `OnCommandOther` event instead.  As you noticed, there are no `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` and `TIdHTTPResponseInfo` parameters provided in that event, so you have to *manually* read and parse **the entire request** yourself, and send an appropriate reply yourself, using `AThread.Connection` to perform socket I/O as needed.  Read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for the HTTP specification.

That being said, this was changed in Indy 10, where `TIdHTTPServer` **DOES** handle all of the parsing, replying, and socket I/O for you, and all of the `OnCommand...` events have `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` and `TIdHTTPResponseInfo` parameters.  So you can easily handle `PUT` and `DELETE` requests in the `OnCommandOther` event.

---

In a future release (most likely not until Indy 11), new `OnCommand...` events will be added for individual requests (`OnCommandPut`, `OnCommandDelete`, etc) so they won't all have to funnel through `OnCommandGet` or `OnCommandOther` anymore.

Comment: It's difficult to get full value from both POST and PUT with Indy 10.  If you turn on ParseParams to parse POST data (for forms or structured POSTs), then with a binary PUT you get a billion conversion exceptions and it's glacially slow.  If you turn off ParseParams, you have to provide your own method to parse POSTs because they made DecodeAndParseParams() protected so you can't use it manually.

Comment: @KurtFitzner `TIdHTTPServer` parses the request body for params only if the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which should *never* be the case for a binary `PUT` (unless the request is malformed). Otherwise the raw request body is left in the `PostStream` for you to handle as needed.

Answer (score 0):

With Indy 10.6.2.0 and Delphi 10.4.2 the HTTP "DELETE" command don't trigger the OnCommandGet event also if is assigned. I can intercept HTTP "DELETE" only with the OnCommandOther event.